# Keep getting logged out

Tags: custom-post-types

I have just created a new custom post type, and while I can see it appear within Wordpress, as soon as I click on it to add some new posts, I just get logged out. The rest of Wordpress admin works fine, it's just this new post type that seems to cause the issue.

Custom post type code below:

```
register_extended_post_type('contact',
  [
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-text',
    'supports' => [ 'page-attributes', 'title', 'slug']
  ],
  [
    # Override the base names used for labels:
    'singular' => 'contact',
    'plural'   => 'Contacts',
    'slug'     => 'contact'
  ]
);

register_extended_taxonomy( 'group', 'contact', array(), array(
    'plural' => 'Groups',
    'slug'   => 'group'
    )
);

register_extended_taxonomy( 'region', 'contact', array(), array(
        'plural' => 'Regions',
        'slug'   => 'region'
    )
);
```

I have seen that this is a common issue with Wordpress, however I have tried all the suggestions about matching site URL/Home URL, clearing cookies, testing in incognito etc, but none of them work. WP Debug is also clean. Any ideas?

### Update

Seems like this issue is a bit more widespread than I thought. I get logged out whenever I search for pages within the admin area (though pagination works fine) and also intermittently it seems when clicking on "Save" when viewing the Permalinks section in admin.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find function `register_extended_post_type` in wordpress code (5.0-some-betta). I would suggest switching to `register_post_type` instead.

P.S.
Same stuff for taxonomies.